# Select helper not populating when bound to list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having some difficulty binding to a list of objects stored in the viewbag.

Here's my view code:

```
<select asp-for="CatID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cats, "CatID", "CatName"))">    
</select>
```

The controller returns the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> List()
{
    SvcClient.SvcClient c = new SvcClient.SvcClient();    
    List<Cat> cats = await c.GetCatsAsync("http://localhost:50370/Lookup/Cats");    
    ViewBag.Cats = cats.ToList();    
    return View();
}
```

Finally, here's the cat class:

```
public int CatID { get; set; }    
public string CatName { get; set; }
public string CatBreed { get; set; }
public string CatNote { get; set; }
```

The select list renders, but it's empty. I understand that I need to bind to an IEnumerable class in order to make this work, but isn't that accomplished by using List<>?

Comment: Are you sure your `GetCatsAsync` call is returning a valid list of Cat objects ?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  I assume your Async web api call is not returning a list of items. Try replacing that with a list of hardcoded Cat objects and see the helper is rendering the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I verified that the list is being populated as coded in the controller and also tried hard coding the data. No dice. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: @christok did you try to use asp-for="CatID" ?

Comment: @hsnbl - Good catch. I did make that change and still no dice. Updating post accordingly.